# How could I access the enum in C++

Tags: c++

Below is code was from C code, you could use bare word B1 B2 B3 directly.
However in C++ it's not allowd, proper namespace is needed, How could I use B1 B2 B3 in C++ way then（what is the correct namespace for B1 B2 B3)?

```
struct A {
    int X;
    union {
        struct B {
            enum { B1, B2, B3 } ABCD;
        }v2;
    } v;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an instance of the struct and access the members:

```
 A a;
 cout << a.v.v2.B1 << a.v.v2.B2 << a.v.v2.B3 << '\n';
```

Comment: Do you mean I can do following: a.v.v2.ABCD = a.v.v2.B1?
Looks a bit odd, but correct way?